# How many restraining orders does Sheldon have?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory

In series ***The Big Bang Theory***, *Sheldon Cooper* has received restraining orders from famous real-world people. He has already received them from:

1. *Leonard Nimoy*
2. *Stan Lee*
3. *Bill Nye*
4. *Carl Sagan*

My questions are:

1. How many restraining orders Sheldon Cooper has got?
2. How did he get those restraining orders and why? It's shown how and
   why he did get from Stan Lee (in episode *The Excelsior Acquisition*) and Bill Nye (in episode *The Proton Displacement*). How and why did he get restraining orders from others?

Comment: He may have others but there is no list of them that I can find.

Comment: As far as I can tell also, it's never specifically mentioned why he got the others....just that he has them.

Comment: I believe from Bill Gates aswell?

Comment: @SuryaTej as far as I remember, no. Gates just only did punched him in the face

Answer (score 11):

**The four you mentioned:**

> Sheldon has restraining orders from his heroes **Leonard Nimoy**, **Carl
>   Sagan**, and **Stan Lee**, as well as television scientist **Bill Nye**.

These are mentioned in the episodes *The Excelsior Acquisition* (Stan Lee), *The Vacation Solution* (Carl Sagan), *The Bath Item Gift Hypothesis* (Leonard Nimoy), and *The Proton Displacement* (Bill Nye).

This is confirmed by [this specialized entry](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Restraining_Orders) on *bigbangtheory.fandom.com*.

Although not mentioned explicitly, **plus one from Zachary Quinto**, as implied in S10E16, *The Allowance Evaporation* (see below for proof).

But there could follow more, of course

---

**The reasons for the other three restraining orders - besides the ones you mentioned - are not all made clear**.

- The only time he mentions Carl Sagan's, is in *The Vacation Solution*, when he walks in on Amy with freshly washed glassware and tells her

  > Here you go! This is now the only lab with glassware washed by a man
  >   with two doctorates and **a restraining order signed by Carl Sagan**.
- And the only time Nimoy's is mentioned, is in *The Excelsior's Acquisition*:

  > *Sheldon*: I’ll tell you where I’ve been. You boys may have had gelato
  >   with Stan Lee and gotten autographed comics, but I saw the inside of
  >   his house and got an autographed application for a restraining order.
  >
  > *Howard*: Sweet.
  >
  > *Sheldon*: Plus, I get to hang out with him again at the hearing. This
  >   is going to look great hanging next to **my restraining order from
  >   Leonard Nimoy**.
- Zachary Quinto's restraining order, however, is due to Sheldon following him into the bathroom:

  > *Amy*: Sheldon, there’s a difference between greeting a friend and **following a celebrity into a bathroom**.
  >   *Sheldon*: If the judge couldn’t explain it to me, I don’t see how you will. If you think [saying hi to seeing someone you know in a public space is] more fun than talking to Zachary Quinto through a stall door, you’re crazy.

  <sup>See [the episode's script](https://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-10-episode-16-the-allowance-evaporation/) for more details</sup>

It probably - and this is pure conjecture - involves his enthusiasm concerning these idols of him mixed with his social ineptitude getting the better hand of him.

---

<sup>Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheldon_Cooper#Personality

https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Leonard_Nimoy

https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/The_Vacation_Solution

https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/The_Allowance_Evaporation#Trivia</sup>

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm lil confused. My question being how many and how did he got'em. I read your answer multiple times, it describes stuff I've said in the question and this line - **But there could follow more, of course.**. Can you please explain to me on that? I'm not clear.

Comment: You say **involves his enthusiasm concerning these idols of him**, so lemme ry to grasp this one. what you mean by that is, Sheldon being social weirdo, he pushes the human contact with celebs that he adore too much and get into trouble because of that. am I getting that right?  *Anyway, I really appreciate your answer,this was  sitting answer-less for long time*

Comment: @Vishwa It's just that these restraining orders, especially because some are mentioned in passing by Sheldon, can pop up anytime: we still have some episodes to go.

Comment: so it's only the four I mentioned?

Comment: At this moment, yes - that is, these are the only ones I found mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417/49).

Comment: You should probably add that this cannot be answered until Young Sheldon is finished.